# How do I make my program resize the buttons and the layout automatically? (Kivy, Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to programming and I challenged myself to code wordle for IOS using python and kivy. The only issue I have right now is that if I resize the window, the design of the app becomes distorted. I believe it is because I assigned each button a "dp" position. Here is my code for one button:  Button:
text: "Q"
size: "35dp", "35dp"
pos: "200dp", "80dp"
I used the same code to position the image, the label and the rest of the buttons.
I have looked into using gridlayout or anchorlayout, but I am unsure on how to position the buttons and labels similarly to the picture below.

[This is the output of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h2ec.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the pos and the size with values

size: 0.2 , 0.2

pos: 0.5 , 0.5

I think that should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).